# Fill area in a excel graph

Tags: excel, graph

There's a way to fill the area like in this?
[image]

And if there is not... what's a way to do it?

*sorry for my poor skill with GIMP and the mouse, but get the idea*

Comment: Area Graph - won't work for your use case ?

Comment: @SachinKohli I tried but I can't make it work. Should be a closed cycle and seems there's no way to do with it. But I could be wrong

Comment: is it like filling area inside scatterplot ? but your x-axis seems like a categorical one... does this help? https://peltiertech.com/fill-under-between-series-in-excel-chart/

Comment: @SachinKohli yep, I made it with scatterplot. It's categorical because it's made from some points for reference but the purpose is to plot a thermodynamics cycle and data will come from a function. (if I understand what do you mean with categorical). Now try with your link